# R: copying cell shading in .xlsx sheet to another

Tags: r, excel, conditional-formatting

I have an .xlsx file called "PASHE". This file contains 21 sheets called:

Cover sheet

Table of Contents

notes

Table3.1a All

Table3.1b All CV

Table3.1a Male

Table3.1b Male CV

Table3.1a Female

Table3.1b Female CV

Table3.1a Full-Time

Table3.1b Full-Time CV

Table3.1a Part-Time

Table3.1b Part-Time CV

Table3.1a Male Full-Time

Table3.1b Male Full-Time CV

Table3.1a Female Full-Time

Table3.1b Female Full-Time CV

Table3.1a Male Part-Time

Table3.1b Male Part-Time CV

Table3.1a Female Part-Time

Table3.1b Female Part-Time CV

I have been able to shade various cells within all the values of the 'CV' sheets using the following code:

```
 cvFive <- createStyle(bgFill = "#5bc0de",
                            fontSize = 12)
      
      cvTen <- createStyle(bgFill = "#428bca",
                           fontSize = 12)
      
      conditionalFormatting(new_workbook,
                            sheet = paste0("Table", AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 12], "b ", sheet, " CV"),
                            rows = 10:(10 + (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 14])) - (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 13]))),
                            cols = 3:17,
                            type = "between",
                            rule = c(5.001, 10),
                            style = cvFive
      )
      
      conditionalFormatting(new_workbook,
                            sheet = paste0("Table", AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 12], "b ", sheet, " CV"),
                            rows = 10:(10 + (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 14])) - (as.numeric(AllWorkbooks[which(AllWorkbooks$Template == wb), 13]))),
                            cols = 3:17,
                            type = "between",
                            rule = c(10.001, 9996),
                            style = cvTen
      )
```

Is there a way for me to copy the shading from the 'CV' sheet to it's equivalent non CV sheet so that the cell shading is the same on both sheets.

E.g, The cell shading on sheet Table3.1a All is the same as Table3.1a All CV, the cell shading on sheet Table3.1a Male is the same as Table3.1a Male CV etc.

I have not known what to try.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would want to do this in R? I am pretty sure you can easily do this in a VisualBasic macro.

Comment: Hi @Patrick, the reason for doing it in R is that I am coding for a project that essentially process thousands of worksheets together and it seems a shame to have to add on a macro to the end of the process - I have been able to shade the cv sheets within the .xlsx files but just can't get the nonCV sheets shaded in a similar way due to the nature of the numeric data within them. I essentially have to copy the formatting of the CV sheet and somehow apply it to the no CV sheets. Also, I have never written a macro in my life!